# Why cant I declare static final variable in non static block?

Tags: java

```
package com.static2;

public class Static {

  final static int y;

    {
        y=8;// error: the value cant be initialized

    }
}
```

We can access static members in non static block but why cant we access static final members in non static blocks?

Answer (score 5):

An instance initializer block (which is what you have in your example) is executed for each instance of your class, which means your `final static` variable would be initialized multiple times (once for each instance). That's not allowed for `final` variables.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `y` is `static` and `final`.

- The `static` keyword makes the variable a member of the class, so an object of the class does not need to be created in order to access the static variable.
- The `final` keyword only allows a variable to be initialised once

You have declared a `static final` variable but not initialised it. This can only be initialised;

1. In its declaration
2. In a static initialiser block

A static initialiser block is defined the same as an instance initialiser but with the keyword `static` before it;

```
static {
    // code
}
```

A static initialiser is inserted into memory only once when a class is compiled and ran.

You have initialised the variable `y` in an instance initialiser. This block of code is ran every time an object is created of the `Static`.

So the reason why your code won't compile is because the `final` variable `y` can be reassigned (albeit to the same value) to the value 8 each time an object of your class is created.

If the variable has to be final create a static initialiser;

```
final static int y;
static {
    y = 8;
}
```

Or else drop the `final`, `static` or both keywords in the variable declaration and keep the instance initialiser as is;

```
int y;
{
    y = 8;
}
```

---

```
static int y;
{
    y = 8;
}
```

---

```
final int y;
{
    y = 8;
}
```